# Accessing windows MongoDB on WSL2 not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tcp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm developing a Node.js application using MongoDB through mongoose, and I'm experiencing an issue while trying to connect to my MongoDB database.

My database is hosted on windows itself, but my application and NPM are running on WSL2 (I recently upgraded from WSL1). I'm using Pengwin (previously WLinux).

When I start the server, I can access it on any browser on Windows. However, I'm not being able to connect to the database that is running on Windows.

**This is how I'm connecting to the database**

```
module.exports = (async () => {
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://172.28.86.172:27017/mydb', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

**That's what I'm getting**

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.28.86.172:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:845:32)
    at /home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10
    at /home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1135:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:344:20)
    at /home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/src/app/persistence.js:6:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/src/app/persistence.js:15:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at /home/alberttocastro/Dev/solutis/solucao-chamados/src/server.js:6:9 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) { '172.28.86.172:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

I don't know if that makes sense, but I suppose this specific port on windows is not being accessible from WSL2. When I run `netstat` on wsl I get this:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:55804         localhost:49152         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:49152         localhost:55804         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 172.28.86.172:41691     #############.msh:51148 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 172.28.86.172:41691     #############.msh:51147 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:35968         localhost:33647         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:33647         localhost:35968         ESTABLISHED

...
```

But when I run `netstat` on Windows PowerShell, I get this:

```
Conexões ativas

  Proto  Endereço local         Endereço externo       Estado
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50798    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50799    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50800    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50801    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50802    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50803    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50804    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50805    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50806    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:50807    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        #############:51199    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50798        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50799        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50800        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50801        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50802        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50803        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50804        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50805        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50806        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50807        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51199        #############:27017    ESTABLISHED
...
```

On windows, I can see the 27017 from MongoDB that I should be connecting. Could somebody help me with a tutorial on how to expose that port on WSL2?

Thank you very much.